# Transferring data from FPGA to PC (new to FPGAs)

Tags: fpga, communication, uart, digital-communications

FPGA beginner here.

I have a Basys2 FPGA board(i code in verilog) and i wish to make it communicate with my PC. Currently it receives data from a slave device and stores it in an 64 bit register. However i want to send this data to my computer for processing, and process it in matlab.

I have done some research. It seems like i can either use EPP API of digilent or just use UART communication.[: seems like this is out of option now, since i don't have access to a UART translator]. However i can't find any explanatory enough examples about any of the methods. Existing examples seem to have a bunch of code "that just works". But lack of explanation makes me unable to adapt it for my

For example there is DeppGetReg(HIF hif, BYTE bAddr, BYTE* pbData, BOOL fOverlap) function on the API but i don't know what to input(specificly the address) to provide to it to read values from FPGA.Only document i could find was in [this link](http://wenku.baidu.com/view/4fb5746aa98271fe910ef9c7.html). I am clueless on UART too.

Here are the available I/O ports of FPGA. The only USB port is used for programming the FPGA, not sure if i can also have communication via that port.
[image]

I would appreciate if you can give any ideas on where to start considering my FPGA board. Thanks in advance.

Comment: VGA port is video output, nothing to do with RS232 UART serial communications. This is actually explained in the BASYS2 "VGA Port" section of the reference manual http://www.digilentinc.com/Data/Products/BASYS2/Basys2_rm.pdf If you want to use a UART, you'll have to add-on an RS232 level translator such as Digilentinc.com PMOD-RS232 using one of the PMOD connectors.

Comment: @MarkU i thought it could be used directly for UART, my mistake. Can i use the single USB port for both programming the FPGA, powering it and making UART communication?

Comment: No, the USB controller on the BASYS2 board only supports JTAG programming and EPP 8-bit parallel read/write. Not serial UART. But RS232 UART is about the easiest peripheral to add, which is why it's such a useful diagnostic. Any RS232 level translator will do, MAX232 for example. Or, directly connect FPGA to an FTDIchip.com FT232.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Looks like i might first give the EPP a try since i don't have access to any additional hardware at the moment. 8 bit read/write sounds fine. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 2):

The USB port can be used to communicate with a design running on the FPGA, as well as for programming it. The Digilent Adept software can be used to interact with a design which implements this protocol; it's also possible to use the Digilent libraries to write your own software which uses this protocol. (I've also written a Perl module, [`Device::Digilent`](https://github.com/duskwuff/Device-Digilent), if you'd prefer that to C.)

Information on the protocol is available at:

https://www.digilentinc.com/Data/Products/ADEPT/DpimRef%20programmers%20manual.pdf

In short, though: there is a parallel bus between the USB interface chip and FPGA consisting of:

- An 8-bit bidirectional bus, used for both addresses and data.
- Address and data strobes, and a write flag, all signalled from the host
- A "wait" signal used by the FPGA to indicate when it has serviced a read/write

The protocol used treats the FPGA as having 256 byte-wide "registers", each of which can be read or written by the host at any time. The order of events for a read is:

- Host asserts the address strobe with the write flag on, and drives the data bus with the index of the register it will be writing.
- Host asserts the data strobe with the write flag off, and the FPGA drives the data bus with the value of the register.

A write works similarly, except the second transfer has the write flag on, and the host drives the data bus with the value to be written.